# Silverstripe: Email variables not displaying correct information

Tags: php, database, variables, silverstripe

SS Version: 3.3.2

I'm working through an already existing project. Basically, there is an "Email us" link on each profile. Click that, fill in details, and an email gets sent to the user. The email variable is not displaying the member email. The contact email is displaying though.

I will show you the contact form PHP, and the email template.

Page.php

```
function profilecontactformajax() {

    $formdata = array(
        'ProfileID' => isset($_REQUEST['ProfileID'])?$_REQUEST['ProfileID']:'',
        'Subject' => isset($_REQUEST['Subject'])?$_REQUEST['Subject']:'',
        'Email' => isset($_REQUEST['Email'])?$_REQUEST['Email']:'',
        'Content' => isset($_REQUEST['Content'])?$_REQUEST['Content']:'',
        'EmailLayout' => 'ProfileContact'
    );

    $formdata['HeaderFontStyles'] = 'font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal;font-size:16px; color:#e60080; line-height:18px';
    $formdata['DefaultFontStyles'] = 'font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal;font-size:12px; color:#6c6e6d; line-height:15px';
    $formdata['SmallFontStyles'] = 'font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal;font-size:10px; color:#e60080;';
    $formdata['FooterFontStyles'] = 'font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal;font-size:12px; color:#6c6e6d;';


    $profile = DataList::create('Profile')->filter(array('ID' => $formdata['ProfileID']))->first();
    if ($profile) {

        //save data
        $o = new ProfileContactMessage();
        $o->Subject = $formdata['Subject'];
        $o->Email = $formdata['Email'];
        $o->Content = $formdata['Content'];
        $o->ProfileID = $formdata['ProfileID'];
        $o->write();

        $formdata['URLSegment'] = $profile->URLSegment;

        //get member details
        $member = DataList::create('Member')->filter(array('ID' => $profile->CreatorMemberID))->first();
        if ($member) {
            $formdata['FirstName'] = $member->FirstName;
            $formdata['MemberEmail'] = $member->Email;
        }


        $to = $profile->Email;
        $from = 'noreply@designersplace.com.au';
        $subject = $formdata['Subject'];

        $email = new Email($from, $to, $subject);
        $email->setTemplate('BaseEmailTemplate');
        $email->populateTemplate($formdata);
        $email->send();

    }

    return $this->customise($formdata)->renderWith('Page_profilecontactformajax');
}
```

BaseEmailTemplate.ss

```
<% if EmailLayout = 'ProfileContact' %>


    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="350" valign="top" style="text-align:left;">          

                    <p style="$DefaultFontStyles">Dear $Name</p>

                    <p style="$DefaultFontStyles">Someone has sent you a message via your Designers Place profile.</p>

                <p style="$DefaultFontStyles"><strong>Subject:</strong><br>$Subject</p>

                <p style="$DefaultFontStyles"><strong>Email:</strong><br>$Email</p>

                <p style="$DefaultFontStyles"><strong>Comments:</strong><br>$Content</p>

                    <p style="$DefaultFontStyles">Warm Regards, </p>

                    <p style="$DefaultFontStyles">Designers Place Support Team. </p>

                </td>
                <td width="40"><img src="{$BaseHref}{$ThemeDir}/images/email/trans.gif" width="40" height="40" border="0"></td>
                <td width="210" valign="top" style="text-align:left;">      
                    <p style="$DefaultFontStyles"><strong>LOGIN DETAILS</strong></p>
                    <p style="$DefaultFontStyles">YOUR USERNAME:<br>$MemberEmail</p>
                    <p style="$DefaultFontStyles">YOUR PASSWORD:<br>******</p>

                    <p><a href="{$BaseHref}Security/login" target="_blank"><img src="{$BaseHref}{$ThemeDir}/images/email/login-now.jpg" width="210" height="43" border="0" class="image_fix"></a></p>

                    <p style="$DefaultFontStyles">VIEW YOUR PROFILE:<br><a href="{$BaseHref}{$URLSegment}" target="_blank">$URLSegment</a></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>






  <% end_if %>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is actually a value being passed through `$_REQUEST['Email']`? What happens if you replace the blank `''` ternary default for "Email" and use 'foo@foo.com' instead? Or just `var_dump($_REQUEST['Email']);`?

Comment: @theruss thanks for the response. Yeah a value is being passed. I'm receiving a response email with one email address (The one filled out in the form), but not the one from the database call.

Comment: OK next question; Are you *sure* there's a value ala `var_dump($member->Email);`? While we're there, what about `$member->FirstName` too? Basically, your check for `if ($member` may not be enough. Try `if ($member && $member->exists())`

Comment: @theruss thanks for your response. FirstName isn't displaying anything. Did a var dump and that's saying "NULL"

Comment: Yep. So I suspect therefore putting in a `die("Do you see something here...? I don't think so")` directly beneath your check for `if($member)` won't do anything. Meaning there is no Member record for the `filter()` criteria you're using.

Comment: @theruss you're a legend. thanks for that. turns out my profile/member ids weren't linked. Linked them up and the email is displaying correctly. Great work.

Comment: Yeah no worries. Mate it really is debugging 101 though: *never* assume *anything* is correct. Trace the route back to source and go from there, not from some arbitrary point in the logic where you *think* the bug *might* be :-) Feel free to up-vote a comment (Not sure if can be converted to an answer...)

Comment: @theruss Thanks. If you can't already tell, I'm rather new to this. Don't even know how to upvote comments!